# Computing the FIRST & FOLLOW sets of a grammar

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, lr1

I have the following grammar:

```
S -> aXab
S -> Y
X -> bYa
X -> epsilon
Y -> Sc
```

I have computed the first and follow sets for this grammar and I would like to know if it is correct. Here is my solution:

```
First Sets:
S -> {a} 
X -> {b,epsilon}
Y -> {a}

Follow Sets:
S -> {$,c} 
X -> {a}
Y -> {c,a}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIRST sets are correct. FOLLOW(Y) should be {$,c,a}

FOLLOW(A) definition is

> FOLLOW(A) of non-terminal A is the set of terminal symbols that can follow in the
> derivation sequence

FOLLOW(Y), check where it is there in the right-hand side

```
        1) X -> bYa
```

when this production is taken for derivation what follows Y is 'a'

```
        2) S -> Y
```

when this production is taken for derivation what follows Y is, What ever that was following S.  FOLLOW(S)={$,c}

```
     FOLLOW(Y)={$,a,c}
```